# Check if Status changed from offline to live problems

Tags: python, discord, notifications, live-streaming

This is my function I made and keep in mind I'm still trying to perfect my craft at coding but I'm in a pinch. The bot properly sends the live notification when a streamer is live but when the next check happens it says they are offline when they are indeed still live and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong anyone have any ideas to what I'm doing wrong?

async def check_youtube_live_status():
global current_youtube_status

```
youtube_channel_ids = ['UCqX-Censored', 'UCbt-Censored', 'UCaL1aZGD-Censored']
excluded_video_ids = ['RYmySdF-Censored', '7-J3f-Censored']

try:
    for channel_id in youtube_channel_ids:
        # Fetch channel title and icon using YouTube Data API
        channel_info_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id={channel_id}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}"
        channel_info_response = requests.get(channel_info_url)

        if channel_info_response.status_code == 200:
            channel_info_data = channel_info_response.json()

            if 'items' in channel_info_data and len(channel_info_data['items']) > 0:
                channel_title = channel_info_data['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
                channel_icon = channel_info_data['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']
            else:
                channel_title = channel_id  # Use channel ID as title if name not found
                channel_icon = None
        else:
            channel_title = channel_id  # Use channel ID as title in case of API error
            channel_icon = None

        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}/live"

        user_agent = UserAgent()
        headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent.random}

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            canonical_link = soup.find('link', {'rel': 'canonical'})

            if canonical_link and 'href' in canonical_link.attrs:
                canonical_url = canonical_link['href']
                is_live = '/watch?v=' in canonical_url and all(video_id not in canonical_url for video_id in excluded_video_ids)

                # Check if status changed from offline to live
                if current_youtube_status.get(channel_id) != is_live:
                    current_youtube_status[channel_id] = is_live
                    channel = bot.get_channel(1187979891988254781)  # Replace with your target Discord channel ID

                    if is_live:
                        if channel:
                            embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f" {channel_title} is currently LIVE on YouTube!",
                                color=0x00FF00  # You can change the color as per your preference
                            )
                            if channel_icon:
                                embed.set_thumbnail(url=channel_icon)  # Set channel icon as thumbnail
                            embed.add_field(
                                name="Watch here",
                                value=f"[Click Here]({canonical_url}) to watch on YouTube!",
                                inline=False
                            )
                            await channel.send(embed=embed)
                    else:
                        if channel:
                            embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f" {channel_title} is currently offline on YouTube.",
                                color=0xFF0000  # You can change the color as per your preference
                            )
                            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                print("No canonical link found.")
        else:
            print("Failed to fetch the channel live page.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error checking YouTube live status: {e}')
```

So I tried looking for different solutions like networking issues or even API issues it doesn't seem to be the cause or reason than I thought of maybe its because its catching the live and not live status not right I've tried using another method of checking status but nothing I've tried hasn't worked.

Comment: It seems that the variable `is_live` is false when you expect it to be true, which means `canonical_url` either does not contain "/watch?v=", or it does contain one of the excluded video ids.  You can print `canonical_url` to see which one of those is true.